# jquery hide certain form elements untill a certain textfield has been populated?

Tags: jquery, forms, hide, show

I have a long signup form and would like to hide a few fields and only show them when a certain input field is populated with text, if the user types some text in this field the other form fields will show.

I have looked at hide and show divs but have some trouble getting form elements hide and show them on a certain trigger ( populating a form with text )

anyone can point me in the right direction on how to implement
such feature in query ? thx in advanche!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since specific problem details weren't provided, I put together a simple example that hopefully will get you started on solving your problem.

[You can see the live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/g6JKy/)

HTML

```
<div id="field1wrapper" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field1" /><span>&lt;-- write on me</span>
</div>
<div id="field2wrapper">
    <label for="field2">Field 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="field2" />
</div>​
```

JavaScript

```
$("#field1").keyup(function()
{
    if($("#field1").val() != "")
    {
        $("#field2wrapper").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#field2wrapper").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});​
```

Comment: ah like that.. using the keyup and val function to check if value is empty, i thought i needed some trigger but count find the right way to do it. I try this think this works exactly fine thx!

Comment: Works perfect only my submit button wich is below the elements I hide is not placed correctly , would you might happen to know a fix for that too? thx!

Comment: @Rubytastic, maybe you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g6JKy/1/ ? What do you mean by not being placed correctly?

Comment: I have #hide div and use your example so all form elements I want to hide are inside #hide, next below is submit button for the form. Then  I set #hide style to height: 0px; But when made visible its height is still 0px but content flows out of div, perhaps I need a toggle method that sets the correct hight for visible and hidden state not sure

Comment: @Rubytastic, why do you set the height to 0? Could you maybe create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? So we can edit it and help solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

***[You could do something like this:](http://jsfiddle.net/EWExA/)***

**HTML:**

```
<label for="txt1">Field 1</label>
<input type="text" id="txt1" />

<label class="secondary hidden" for="txt2">Field 2</label>
<input class="secondary hidden" type="text" id="txt2" />

<label for="txt3">Field 3</label>
<input type="text" id="txt3" />

<label class="secondary hidden" for="txt4">Field 4</label>
<input class="secondary hidden" type="text" id="txt4" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.hidden { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
```

**jQuery:**​

```
var $txt1 = $("#txt1"), 
    $secondary = $(".secondary");

$txt1.keyup(function() { 
    $secondary.toggleClass("hidden", $(this).val() == ""); 
});​
```

Using ***[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)*** allows you to pass in a boolean value for adding or removing the class. And binding to ***[keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup)*** allows you to immediately hide or show depending on the value of the field vs waiting for onblur as you would with ***[change](http://api.jquery.com/change)***.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the JQuery change() event handler?

http://api.jquery.com/change/

There's examples of how to use it to trigger events on the page.